# Product > Archive error in Xcode related to Signing & Capabilities

Tags: xcode, macos, archive, provisioning-profile, signing

I have an Xcode project that I want to deploy to App Store.

When I run **Product >Archive** I receive an "Archive failed"  error in the Signing & Capabilities section.
(Please see the screenshots)

I tried both "**Automatically Manage Signing**" checked and unchecked.
When "Automatically Manage Signing" is unchecked, I receive 2 errors:

*"Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website..."*
and
*"No profiles for 'net.myprojectname' were found. XCode could not find any IOS development provisioning profiles matching 'net.myprojectname'*

When "Automatically Manage Signing" is checked, I receive those same 2 errors even before I run Product>Archive.

I do have a provisioning profile that appears to be visible to Xcode when the Automatically Manage Signing is unchecked.

When I try to just build the project and run it on the simulator, it works fine.
Again, all I want is to deploy the project to the App Store.

Do I really need a registered iPhone in order to do so? (I don't have one)
Or is there another way to solve it?

Thank you in advance for any help.
[image: Auto signing option]
[image: Non-auto signing]

I tried Automatically Manage Signing checked and unchecked. I have created (and recreated) provisioning profile that matches my project name. I have tried running regular build beforehand. None of these actions solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you did those steps first:

1. Register that *net.myprojectname* identifier in the Developer section [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/bundleId/add/bundle).
2. Have an app created using that identifier in the [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps).

If you did those the automatic signing management should work for you with no issue. Also registering a device is pretty straight forward (if you own one, obviously), just run the app on a device and it gets registered for you.

Comment: I do have the correct identifier net.myprojectname in the Identifiers section. I also have the app net.myprojectname registered in the App Store Connect that uses the net.myprojectname identifier. Xcode insists on having a Provisioning Profile, and Provisioning Profile insists on having a device - this is where it seems I am stuck...

Comment: Weird. Is the first time you try to upload it? Did you uploaded any other apps in the past? I don't think it will be the issue, but normally the domain is net.author.project. For example com.aone.Keka, being com.aone de domain/author and Keka the project.

Answer (score 0):

I  found the solution: my provisioning profile was for release, but Xcode (for reasons unknown to me) was trying to use a (non-existent) development provisioning profile.
Once I tweaked Xcode to use the release profile, things started to work and I was able to build the archive.